# Remove grid lines in highcharter R

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have created my own theme for graphing from the highcharter R package. I am looking to remove the white horizontal lines in the background. I have tried setting "gridLineWidth" to 0 with no luck. Here is a picture of my current graph. Any help would be appreciated.

```
my_theme = hc_theme(
  colors = c(
    "#5daa45","#0066b2","#d51f3a",   "#983794", "#ebe71c", "#5196bc"),
  chart = list(
    backgroundColor = "#242932",
    gridLineWidth = 0
  ),
  title = list(
    style = list(
      color = "#e8e8e8"
   #   fontFamily = "Lato"
    )
  ),
  subtitle = list(
    style = list(
      color = "#e8e8e8"
    #  fontFamily = "Shadows Into Light"
    )
  ),
  legend = list(
    itemStyle = list(
  #    fontFamily = "Tangerine",
      color = "#e8e8e8"
    ),
    itemHoverStyle = list(
      color = "#e8e8e8"
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not API for `*chart*.gridLineWidth` property: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.gridLineWidth

However, there is one for `*yAxis*.gridLineWidth` and `*xAxis*.gridLineWidth`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.gridLineWidth and https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineWidth :)